# Pic micro controller

Tags: pic, audio, rom, pic16f

i am programming pic microcontroller using mikro c  , i want to store array of 8 bit samples  generated from audacity (it's a software used to generate header file from audio file) , i got one header file and copied it to one new file and saved as "const sample[ ]={hex samples};"
And saved it in main file i included this header file but I am facing error " there is not enough rom space" , please help me out guys,,,thanks

Comment: I guess probably because you are using free version of Mikro C which limits the size of the file (i.e. long time ago, it was 1 or 2Kbyte), therefore, you need to upgrade the version.

Comment: No sir i am using registered one and I have programmed it for many application but I am new to audio , pwm and rom use

Comment: Then you need to provide us with a minimal working example that regenerates the error so that we can see what's going on.

Comment: How big is the header file (in bytes?)  How big is the ROM in your PIC (in bytes?)  Which is bigger?  See any problem?

Comment: And how many bytes are you going to store in your array? Isn't it possible that there indeed is not enough memory? Check: How much ROM do you have, how much rom is needed for your entire code, when you keep that array empty? The rest is what's left for your array.

Comment: It's pic16f887 having around 8k and header file is around 3k of size,, and as I removing samples byte from array i can compile it , but I want to store 2 second audio speech in array , how it should be done?

Comment: @user103110 Lower the sample rate or implement some sort of compression. Something like [LZO](http://www.oberhumer.com/opensource/lzo/) might be sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you can't cram 20 pounds of data into a 10 pound memory.

Either try to store less data or get a bigger memory.

Also look carefully how exactly you are storing the data in the program memory of the PIC.  You are thinking of this in terms of "files", which makes no sense.  To use microcontrollers effectively, you have to actually *understand* what is going on at the low levels.  Make sure these byte samples are really stored in successive bytes of program memory.  Also make sure your compiler isn't imposing some arbitrary memory size restriction.

The easiest way to make sure the data is being stored effectively in program memory with the right format is to use assembly language for that one module.  Note that on a PIC 18 (you didn't say which PIC, let alone what family), you need to put this data into a CODE_PACK section, not a normal CODE section.

Answer (score 2):

You said that you declared the storage as:

```
const sample[ ]={hex samples};
```

I'm not sure about the mikro c compiler, but most c compilers will default to storing that as an array of 16-bit integers. Since you said that you have 8-bit samples you need to declare the storage as

```
const unsigned char sample [ ]={hex samples};
```

This should take up half of the memory space.